# Illegible character when reading the stream of data received by the server, how do I correct that?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

Details about the application:

- Developed under Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10)
- Designed on the [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) platform with C# and the XAML language

The application receives information from a remote server. A connection via Socket is used for communication between the two parties.

The server sent by frame a message, and in this message we find several essential elements with each a size and a different definition as can be seen below:

Content of each message:

```
- Name: ID Message / Type : UINT16 / Size : 4 bytes
- Name: ID Device/ Type : UINT8 / Size : 4 bytes
- Name: Temperature / Type : UINT16 / Size : 4 bytes
- Name: Activation / Type : BOOLEAN / Size : 4 bytes
- Name: Weather / Type : STRING[32] / Size : 16 bytes
```

To recover the data transmitted via the socket, the application has a background task that takes care of retrieving all the information.

Here is my code which is therefore in the background task:

```
StreamReader reader;
int SizeBuffer = 2048;
int SizeReceive = 0;

reader = new StreamReader(socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());
string result;

result = "";
while (true)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[SizeBuffer];
    SizeReceive = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, SizeBuffer);

    int i = 0;

    Debug.WriteLine("Text 1 : ")
    while (i < 2047)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(buffer[i]);
        i++;
    }

    string data = new string(buffer);

    if (data.IndexOf("\0") >= 0 || reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        result = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf("\0"));
        break;
    }
    result += data;
}

Debug.WriteLine("Text 2 : " + result);
dataString = result;
```

I am using two `Debug.WriteLine`s to see my incoming data.

That's where there is a problem. For the message Text1, I get this kind of character: `������������������������`

And for the Text2 message, I get a single character: `�`

How can I get my message completely and store it in each of the parameters listed above in relation to its type and corresponding size?

Comment: Rather than reading `char`s from the stream, how about reading raw bytes since `char` represents a 2-byte UTF-16 character. You're probably seeing the garbled output because of the assumption of character encoding.

Comment: How does a `STRING[32]` fit into `Size : 16 bytes` ? What _is_ a STRING[32] ?

Comment: @phuzi I did not find a method that works to read bytes directly ... If you have an example It would help me a lot

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't know ... It's written like that in the server documentation ... It's really strange

Comment: Do you even know _how many_ bytes there are in a a message?

Comment: @henkholterman No it may depend on the message that's the problem. I would be able to display at least the beginning that would be easier afterwards

Comment: The "Content of each message:" part suggests a fixed size.

Comment: @henkholterman Yes, each parameter has a fixed size. On the other hand a message sent from the server must absolutely contain the Message ID and the Device ID but not necessarily the weather indication on each.

Comment: That makes no sense, If I leave out the temperature, how does it know it's not the 'Activation' that is missing?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, I know it sounds weird but in relation to our Message ID, we can know what the parameters will be afterwards. I explained myself badly. I managed to recover the data in hexadecimal using a new method.

Comment: "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
try
{
    DataReader reader1 = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
    reader1.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
    uint numFileBytes = await reader1.LoadAsync(2048);
    byte[] byArray = new byte[numFileBytes];
    reader1.ReadBytes(byArray);
    string test = BitConverter.ToString(byArray);

    Debug.WriteLine("Conversion : " + test);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ERROR LECTURE : " + exception.Message);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think, this is the solution?

Comment: @UweKeim I tested the solution in my project and it works perfectly. I receive hexadecimal and then I convert it to use it.

Answer (score 1):

A black diamond with a question mark character is a placeholder for unrecognized characters. It looks like a problem with the encoding of data received from the server.

The default StreamReader constructor with one argument uses UTF-8 encoding. Maybe your server sends data in another encoding.

Try to explicitly specify the encoding using the [`StreamReader(stream, encoding)` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_).